# Git Version Upgraded and Few links in Chrome not clickable

Tags: git

Recently upgraded git version in Centos6.7 server from 2.1.2 to 2.5.3 by executing the below commands:

1: Install Required Packages

```
# yum install curl-devel expat-devel gettext-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel
# yum install  gcc perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
```

2: Uninstall old Git RPM

```
# yum remove git
```

3: Download and Compile Git Source

```
# cd /usr/src
# wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.5.3.tar.gz
# tar xzf git-2.5.3.tar.gz


# cd git-2.5.3
# make prefix=/usr/local/git all
# make prefix=/usr/local/git install
# echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc
# source /etc/bashrc
```

4: Check Git Version

```
# git --version
```

git version 2.5.3

But after the upgrade, am noticing that ONLY in Google Chrome, few links in the right rail ONLY in this page -

www.indusladies.com/forums

is not clickable. Any idea how to fix. Thanks.